# Routing Undefined Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

How would you set up the routing in ASP.NET MVC in order to route paths with undefined controllers to a specific controller.

For example, I have a UserController, so I would want http://example.com/user to route to the UserController, but I would want http://example.com/supercoolproject to route to the ProjectController in order to find the Super Cool Project item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't use http://example.com/supercoolproject address. Instead, it should be http://example.com/project/supercool, but if you want to use address in http://example.com/{projectname}project format, you can define rule in global.asax like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductByNameRule",
    "{projectName}project",
    new { controller = "Project", action = "ByName" }
);
```

and have

```
public ActionResult ByName(string projectName) {
}
```

in `ProjectController`.

Comment: This isn't my ideal solution unfortunately, but it is workable for the time being

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom controller factory to do this.

http://keyvan.io/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc

In the CreateController method of the custom controller factory's IControllerFactory implementation first try to create the controller using DefaultControllerFactory, then if this fails create an instance of your fallback controller and return it instead.